# How to make a duplicate of the running .exe in perl?

Tags: windows, perl, file, copy

Suppose the current running perl .exe is `C:\1\ABC.exe`. I want to make a duplicate of the `ABC.exe` itself in another directory using a Perl script only, copying the file `ABC.exe` to `C:\2\` for example. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean that `C:\1\ABC.exe` is the Perl interpreter?  If so, how did it get that name, and why do you want to make a duplicate of it?  If not, in what sense is it "the current running perl .exe"?

Comment: I've edited your question.  Please verify that my edit hasn't lost the original meaning.  (I'm not at all sure what that meaning is.)

Comment: normal OS command `cp ....` doesn't work for you? You can also try File::Copy

Comment: Of course the command `cp ...` doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Are you going to create a virus in Perl?

Answer (score 3):

Is that a really weird way of asking how to copy a file in Perl?

```
use File::Copy qw( copy );
copy("C:\\1\\ABC.exe", "C:\\2")
   or die("Copy failed: $!\n)";
```

[File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy)